# Tags: [dataannotations], [data-annotations] and [data-annotation]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I've asked a question about MVC on Stack Overflow when I saw that there are 3 tags for (apparently) the same thing:

[dataannotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataannotations) (1710+14+1+1),
[data-annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-annotations) (115+14+0+1) and
<strike>[data-annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-annotation) (11+1+0+1)</strike> 0

I have to admit that I'm not sure about what we should do in these cases, but I think these tags should be merged, right?

Comment: 1725, 130, 16 is the tag count. I personally like [data-annotations] best. That would mean retagging 130+16 questions to [dataannotations] and then rename that tag?

Comment: I've used [dataannotations] simply because it's the most popular, but I also prefer [data-annotations].

Comment: Gather votes for merging all into [data-annotations], and then let a mod make the merge. Though look through a representative sample each to make sure it's right.

Comment: @rene - Thanks for the clarification!  :)